Very slow Quantum Neural Networks
the following code is very slow...
How can I speed it up?
Below you will see all the code I have written and how I used JAX and PennyLane. You will see the circuit I created and the model I built, which I believe are correct, but any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. The code works, but it is too slow, and I cannot understand why it is unable to complete even the first epoch of training due to its slowness.
import pennylane as qml
from pennylane import numpy as np
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import random
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from jax.lib import xla_bridge

# Check if JAX is using the GPU
print(xla_bridge.get_backend().platform)  # It should return 'gpu' if CUDA is correctly configured.

# Parameters
n_qubits = 4    # Number of qubits (equivalent to the number of pixels for a 3x3 kernel)
n_layers = 2    # Number of layers in the circuit
n_train = 100    # Number of training samples
n_test = 50      # Number of test samples

# Load and preprocess MNIST data
mnist_dataset = keras.datasets.mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist_dataset.load_data()

# Add an extra dimension for convolution channels using jax numpy
train_images = jnp.array(train_images[..., None]) 
test_images = jnp.array(test_images[..., None])

# Reduce dataset size for testing
train_images = train_images[:n_train]
train_labels = train_labels[:n_train]
test_images = test_images[:n_test]
test_labels = test_labels[:n_test]

# Normalize pixels between 0 and 1
train_images = train_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0

print(train_images.shape)
print(train_labels.shape)

# Quantum device
dev = qml.device("default.qubit", wires=n_qubits)

# Quantum circuit
@jax.jit
@qml.qnode(dev, interface="jax")
def circuit(inputs, weights):
    # Data embedding
    qml.AngleEmbedding(inputs, wires=range(n_qubits), rotation="Y")
    # Entanglement layers
    qml.BasicEntanglerLayers(weights, wires=range(n_qubits))
    # PauliZ operator measurements
    return [qml.expval(qml.PauliZ(wires=i)) for i in range(n_qubits)]

# Class for quantum convolutional layer
class QuantumConv2D:
    def __init__(self, kernel_size, stride, n_qubits, n_layers):
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.stride = stride
        self.n_qubits = n_qubits
        self.n_layers = n_layers
        self.weight_shapes = {"weights": (n_layers, n_qubits)}
        #print("Initialized QuantumConv2D")

    def __call__(self, X, weights):
        #print("Starting QuantumConv2D call")
        batch_size, height, width, channels = X.shape
        output_height = (height - self.kernel_size) // self.stride + 1
        output_width = (width - self.kernel_size) // self.stride + 1

        outputs = jnp.empty((batch_size, output_height, output_width, self.n_qubits), dtype=jnp.float32)

        # Iterate over image blocks
        for i in range(0, height - self.kernel_size + 1, self.stride):
            #print(f"Processing row: {i}")
            for j in range(0, width - self.kernel_size + 1, self.stride):
                #print(f"Processing column: {j}")
                patch = X[:, i:i+self.kernel_size, j:j+self.kernel_size, :]
                patch = patch.reshape((batch_size, -1))

                # Calculate output for each example in the batch
                for b in range(batch_size):
                    #print(f"Calling circuit batch {b}, row {i}, column {j}")
                    outputs = outputs.at[b, i // self.stride, j // self.stride, :].set(
                        circuit(patch[b], weights)
                    )
                
        #print("Ending QuantumConv2D call")
        return outputs

# Class for the full model
class QuantumCNN:
    def __init__(self, input_shape, n_qubits, n_layers, kernel_size=2, stride=1, output_size=10):
        #print("Initializing QuantumCNN")
        self.qconv = QuantumConv2D(kernel_size, stride, n_qubits, n_layers)
        self.n_qubits = n_qubits
        self.output_size = output_size
        height, width = input_shape[1:3]
        output_height = (height - kernel_size) // stride + 1
        output_width = (width - kernel_size) // stride + 1
        self.flatten_size = output_height * output_width * n_qubits
        self.fc_weights = random.normal(random.PRNGKey(42), (self.flatten_size, output_size))

    def forward(self, X, q_weights):
        #print("Starting forward QuantumCNN")
        qconv_output = self.qconv(X, q_weights)
        #print("QuantumConv2D output calculated")
        qconv_output_flattened = qconv_output.reshape(X.shape[0], -1)
        logits = jnp.dot(qconv_output_flattened, self.fc_weights)
        #print("Logits calculated")
        return logits

# Loss function
#@jax.jit
def cross_entropy_loss(logits, labels):
    # Convert labels to one-hot
    one_hot_labels = jax.nn.one_hot(labels, num_classes=10)
    return -jnp.mean(jnp.sum(one_hot_labels * jax.nn.log_softmax(logits), axis=-1))

# Parameter update function
@jax.jit
def update(params, X, y, learning_rate):
    # Compute the gradient of the loss with respect to the parameters
    #print("Measuring Loss")
    grads = jax.grad(loss_fn)(params, X, y)
    # Update parameters with SGD
    return jax.tree_map(lambda p, g: p - learning_rate * g, params, grads)

# Generic loss function
@jax.jit
def loss_fn(params, X, y):
    q_weights, fc_weights = params
    input_shape = X.shape 
    model = QuantumCNN(input_shape=input_shape, n_qubits=n_qubits, n_layers=n_layers)
    logits = model.forward(X, q_weights)
    return cross_entropy_loss(logits, y)

# Initialization parameters
q_weights = random.normal(random.PRNGKey(0), (n_layers, n_qubits))
params = (q_weights, random.normal(random.PRNGKey(42), (n_qubits * 24 * 24, 10)))

# Training
learning_rate = 0.01
num_epochs = 1
batch_size = 10

@jax.jit
def train_step(params, X_batch, y_batch, learning_rate):
    # Compute gradients of the loss function
    grads = jax.grad(loss_fn)(params, X_batch, y_batch)
    
    # Print gradients to monitor them (optional, can be very detailed)
    print("Gradients:", grads)
    
    # Update parameters
    params = jax.tree_map(lambda p, g: p - learning_rate * g, params, grads)
    
    # Print updated parameters (optional)
    print("Updated Parameters:", params)
    
    return params

# Run training with optimized step
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}")
    for i in range(0, len(train_images), batch_size):
        X_batch = train_images[i:i+batch_size]
        y_batch = train_labels[i:i+batch_size]
        
        # Calculate updated parameters
        params = train_step(params, X_batch, y_batch, learning_rate)
        
        # You can also print the loss after each batch (if loss_fn is well defined)
        if i % 100 == 0:  # Print every 100 batches
            loss_value = loss_fn(params, X_batch, y_batch)
            print(f"Batch {i}/{len(train_images)} - Loss: {loss_value}")


# print("Starting training")
# for epoch in range(num_epochs):
#     print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs}")
#     for i in range(0, len(train_images), batch_size):
#         #print(f"Processing batch {i // batch_size + 1}")
#         X_batch = train_images[i:i+batch_size]
#         y_batch = train_labels[i:i+batch_size]

#         params = update(params, X_batch, y_batch, learning_rate)

#         batch_loss = loss_fn(params, X_batch, y_batch)
#         print(f"Batch {i // batch_size + 1} Loss: {batch_loss:.4f}")

#     train_loss = loss_fn(params, train_images, train_labels)
#     print(f"Epoch {epoch+1} Loss: {train_loss:.4f}")

# Testing
q_weights, fc_weights = params

# Initialize the model with input shape
input_shape = train_images.shape  # Assume train_images has shape (batch_size, height, width, channels)
print(f"Input shape: {input_shape}")
model = QuantumCNN(input_shape=input_shape, n_qubits=n_qubits, n_layers=n_layers)

# Calculate logits for test examples
logits = model.forward(test_images, q_weights)

predictions = jnp.argmax(logits, axis=1)

accuracy = jnp.mean(predictions == test_labels)
print(f"Test Accuracy: {accuracy * 100:.2f}%")

# Show the correct and predicted result for the first N examples
N = 10  # Number of examples to display
for i in range(N):
    print(f"Example {i+1}: True Label: {test_labels[i]}, Predicted: {predictions[i]}")


I would like to understand the reasons behind the slow performance and the high computational cost I’m experiencing, despite using GPUs from powerful servers to run the code. It seems that the process is taking an unexpectedly long time, and I’m looking for insights into potential inefficiencies or bottlenecks. I would greatly appreciate any recommendations or strategies on how to optimize the code or make adjustments to improve speed and reduce computational load throughout the entire process.
